# Changing httpservletrequest to restcontroller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, servlets

I have a servlet class which has a method "process", over ridden from HttpServlet

```java
@override
protected void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    String inXml = null;
    //some more code..
}
```

It is reading whatever is coming into the servlet.

How can I rewrite this as rest controller in spring??

Answer (score 1):

Just code it as:

```java
@RestController
public ReturnType process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response {
    //...
}
```

and check [this part](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods) of the Spring MVC documentation as well:

> `@RequestMapping` handler methods have a flexible signature and can choose from a range of supported controller method arguments and return values.

Note, that:

- whatever you return from your Rest-Controller turns into HTTP Response Body;
- you can define `@RestController` on the class level.

Comment: currently my servlet is not returning anything, it is using outputsream only,

Comment: out = response.getOutputStream();
    if (outXml == null) {
     outXml = (String) genericDTO.getObj();
    }
    out.write(outXml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.flush();
    if (fwlogger.isDebugEnabled())
     fwlogger.debug(requestId + " Response XML : " + outXml);

Comment: how can i make this outputstream into a returntype??

Comment: in rest concept, whatever i am returning shud come as a response right??

Comment: That is another question, which means that you're not focused on what you are asking. 1. why do you want to return OutputStream? what you're trying to achieve? Just return String or whatever type you wish.

Comment: `@RestController = @Controller + @ResponseBody`. So, whatever you do return is a HTTP Response message body.

Comment: i want to give a response back just like the present httpservlet without changing it, i.e flow shud go the same